# Automatically click segmentControl with index 0 on ViewDidAppear

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I am hoping to "automate" a click on the segmentController with the index of 0.

My tabBar-based app has multiple segmentControllers in a tab in the ViewDidAppear method, I would like to automatically have it "click" the first segmented controller.

```
if (segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    //stuff here
}

if (segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    //stuff here
}
```

Does anyone know how I might accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating it programmatically, you could lazy load it like this:

```
@interface ExampleViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
- (void)segmentedControlClicked:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentedControl;
@end


@implementation ExampleViewController

- (UISegmentedControl *)segmentedControl
{
    if (!_segmentedControl)
    {
        NSArray *items = @[@"First", @"Second", @"Third"];
        _segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];
        [_segmentedControl addTarget:self 
                           action:@selector(segmentedControlClicked:) 
                           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        [_segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];   // Set Default selection

        CGRect frame = _segmentedControl.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);     // Move to wherever you need it
        [self.view addSubview:_segmentedControl];
    }
    return _segmentedControl;
}

- (void)segmentedControlClicked:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentedControl
{

    // Whatever your code is goes here...

}
@end
```

If you're wanting a method to be called also initially, you can call it within your `viewDidLoad:` method as such:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];  // Set desired default index (optional if set in lazy load as shown above)
    [self segmentedControlClicked:self.segmentedControl];
}
```

This would hence simulate a click on desired default index.

Be careful putting the above into `viewDidAppear:` (you could if you really wanted to) because anytime the view comes to the front, this method will be called (in example, if this view controller presents a **modal** view controller, once the modal is dismissed, this view controller's `viewDidAppear:` method will be called).

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! Im getting a compiler error on the second line of the method called within the viewDidLoad: "No visible @interface for 'ProfileViewController' declares the selector 'segmentedControlClicked:'" Do you know why this might be?

Comment: This is an "unrecognized selector" error... it means that you didn't define the method `segmentedControlClicked:` . Please see my revised answer which shows more code.

Comment: Why was this down voted? There's nothing wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `selectedSegmentIndex` property on your `UISegmentedControl` in your `viewDidAppear` (or `viewDidLoad`) method.

`self.segmentedController.selectedSegemntIndex = 1;`

[UISegmentedControl Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)